# Using sendEmail with Gmail

Tags: email, gmail, sendmail

I try to sending an E-Mail via Gmail and sendEmail. I have try some configurations but nothing works.

```
sendEmail \
-o tls=yes \
-f mymailaccount@gmail.com \
-t email-receiver@gmail.com \
-s smtp.gmail.com:587 \
-xu mymailaccount@gmail.com \
-xp some-safty-password \
-u Hello World \
-m This is an E-Mail text.

RESULT: sendEmail[11181]: ERROR => ERROR => SMTP-AUTH: Authentication to smtp.gmail.com:587 failed.
```

```
sendEmail \
-o tls=yes \
-f mymailaccount@gmail.com \
-t email-receiver@gmail.com \
-s smtp.gmail.com:465 \
-xu mymailaccount@gmail.com \
-xp some-safty-password \
-u Hello World \
-m This is an E-Mail text.

RESULT:  sendEmail[11213]: ERROR => smtp.gmail.com:465 returned a zero byte response to our query.
```

I have try with and without TLS. I have activate POP, IMAP and SMTP on Gmail account.

Whats wrong with my config?

Comment: Good news is that this works flawlessly from Ubuntu 18.04.  Have you had a look at the 'Use less secure apps' section of Gmail: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255 This can be found under 'Manage my account' --> Secure Account --> Third Part Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a solution with comment from andrew.46. I have to activate 'use less secure apps' in Google-Account (https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/security?hl=de). Than following code works:

```
sendEmail \
-o tls=yes \
-f mymailaccount@gmail.com \
-t email-receiver@gmail.com \
-s smtp.gmail.com:587 \
-xu mymailaccount@gmail.com \
-xp some-safty-password \
-u Hello World \
-m This is an E-Mail text.
```